# What does this Code validation formula mean?

Tags: c++

```
 while(cin>>seats){
        
        if(seats>=0 &&seats<36){
            const int row=(seats-1)/7;   // <-
            const int col=(seats-1)%7;   // <-
            arr[row][col]=0;
            std::cout<<"\n Seat successfully reserved!\n";
```

The code about constant in the lines marked with `<-` is confusing for me. How it updates the seats and why that formula of dividing by 7 and modulo 7. I can provide the whole code if it's not clear enough. It is about seat reservation program for my homework.

Comment: Because the number of columns in the array is 7?

Comment: It is more mistery for me that `1` is subtracted from `seats` while allowing `0` as the value of `seats`.

Comment: yes, please do provide complete code. see [mcve]

Comment: Please describe your observations while applying with pen and paper these two formulas to all numbers 0 ...35. Can you observe a pattern? Does that pattern make sense to you for reserving seats in a grid of e.g. 7x5?

Comment: Given that the max is 36, it should probably divide by 6, not 7.

Comment: @rustyx Max is 35-1=34.

Comment: You have 36 seats laid out as a matrix of 6 rows and 6 columns. Given a seat number from 0 to 35, you assign the row dividing by 7 and the column getting the modulo of 7. Then you unset that (row, col) combination to mark it as reserved.

Comment: @rustyx is right. If your input is between 0 and 35, you should write `row = seat / 6` and `col = seat % 6`.

Comment: The maximum which makes it past the `if` is 35. The calculation is done with that minus one. I see a maximum of 34. It would make more sense to doubt the two `-1`than the two `7`s, because, the `-1`s also cause a minimum of -1 to be processed, as MikeCAT observed and got agreements on. A 36 is never involved.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you had 100 seats, in 10 rows of 10 seats each; and the seats, rows, and columns are numbered starting at 0, like so:

```
Seat  0 is in row 0, column 0.
Seat  1 is in row 0, column 1.
...
Seat  9 is in row 0, column 9.
Seat 10 is in row 1, column 0.
Seat 11 is in row 1, column 1.
Seat 12 is in row 1, column 2.
...
Seat 99 is in row 9, column 9.
```

Get it? Well,

- the row index is always the seat index, divided by 10;
- the column index is what remains after you subtract the seats in full previous rows, i.e. the column index is the seat index modulo 10.

In your case, you have different numbers of seats, rows, and columns, but the principle is the same.

---

Having said that... if you have 36 seats, are you sure the rows and columns shouldn't be of length 6? If they should, then you should have `/ 6`  and `% 6`, not `/7` and `% 7`. Also, as @MikeCAT points out - if seats is 0-based, there shouldn't be a subtraction of 1.

Comment: I get it now. thank you so much!

The program works well.. My seats is arr[5][7].
If I don't use -1 the seats the is reserved is the one after it.
If the input is =1
the seat that is reserved is 2...